# Usage of select() for timeout

Tags: c, select, network-programming, sftp

I was only able to set maximum of 20 seconds as the timeout parameter in select () API. Whatever value i gave above 20, select() is returning after 20 seconds itself...
So i was trying to write a loop for the timeout of 1 minute like this

```
    int timeoutcount = 0;
    do
    {
    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(sock,&fd);
    timeout.tv_sec = 20;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    rc = select (sock+1,&fd,null,null,&timeout);
    if(rc ==0)
    timeoutcount += 20;
    }
    while(rc ==0 && timeoutcount <60)
```

please help me out...am i going in the correct way?
If so,select returns 1 after first timeout..help me figure this out too
Note: i'm using it in objective C

Comment: How do you know you are timing out, and not getting events on `sock` ?

Comment: @nos When i was trying for first time, i set the timeout as 60 seconds. I got the events on 'sock' after 20 seconds itself, though my network cable was unplugged. After that when i gave the timeout as 20 seconds, it was working correctly..

Comment: well, you need to handle the socket event. regardless of whether your cable is unplugged or not. You might get an event because the fact it is unplugged, or something is timing out at the socket level, depending on what you're doing. select returns when: EITHER a socket has an event, OR the timeout occurs. select() works exactly as advertised. If you do not handle the socket event, you just get the same event next time you call select on that socket.

Comment: @nos I accept. But may i know why select() is returning an event at 22 seconds though my timeout is 60 seconds (P.S My network cable was unplugged when i was testing this case).

Comment: because an event on the socket happened at that time. You need to handle that event, that is: read() from the socket to learn WHY there was an event. Events on the socket and the timeout parameter to select have no relation whatsoever, except the timeout will fire if none of the sockets have an event within that time.

Answer (score 10):

There is no 20-second maximum for the timeout to select -- something else (most likely data being ready-for-read on your socket) must have been causing select() to return early.  If you really only want to use select() as a way to sleep, try calling it like this:

```
struct timeval tv = {600, 0};   // sleep for ten minutes!
if (select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) perror("select");
```

Comment: I dont want to use select as sleep functionality. It should wait on socket for events for timeout.

Comment: select() will return as soon as an event occurs on a registered socket, or if no socket events occur, then it will return after the time indicated by your timeout value elapses.  So if you want to handle socket events as well as get a timeout, you need to handle the socket events as they occur, and then call select() again afterwards (with an appropriately reduced timeout value).

Comment: I have a basic doubt. Will Select() return some event even though there is no network connection?

Comment: Sure, it can do that; in particular a TCP socket could eventually time out trying to send, and then select() would return with the socket flagged as ready-for-read, and then read()/recv() would return an error to indicate that TCP connection was broken.  I'm not sure if a UDP socket would do the same, but it might.