# How to implement Javascript's setTimeout() function in C (not C++)

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, settimeout, glib

The title says it all.
I have seen solutions in C++. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821573/c-modern-way-to-implement-jss-settimeout) and some which (also C++) are rather old. 
I am open to using glib or any other opensource library. I care only for Linux implementation.

I came across glib's [timer functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Timers.html) but they are all synchronous in nature and not close to what setTimeout() does.

I can think of one solution of having a separate thread which continually, in a loop, checks if a timer, such as the one provided by Glib, has expired and then fire the corresponding function. Of course, that would be ridiculously inefficient.

I also came across this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074380/want-to-implement-timeout-for-one-function-in-c) which suggests the use of alarm(2). It can be used but granularity is in seconds only.

EDIT: Alas alarm() cancels any previously set alarm()

Comment: Have a look at the alarm and settimer functions.  alarm generates signals so you'll need a signal handler.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do while waiting, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9798948/1741542

Comment: Looking at your g_timer link, this seems like some wrapper around [gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)

Comment: It depends on your operating system. C by itself doesn't have any notion of time events or asynchronous execution. If you want the latter. you probably need an OS-specific threads library. There is a threads library in C11 but few compilers seem to support it. `alarm` has a limited utility as not all functions may be called from a signal handler.

Comment: @cup I read on setitimer (I think you meant that and not settimer). The problem I find (after reading the man page) is " A process has only one of each of the three types of timers."

Comment: I added the [tag:linux] tag since you say that's the OS you care about, and since this question won't have an answer in standard C.

Comment: Note that if you go from single-threaded event based app architecture to multithreaded apps, be prepared for a world of pain. I'd look for "C event library" instead of threads for stuff like this.

Comment: @hyde And how will a "C event library" help in this case? Any such library will still need a timer to trigger an event asynchronously.  Also, I stay away from event libraries (libevent, for example) because they are primarily (IMHO) intended for those looking for multi-platform support.  If the platform is fixed, then it is a lot more easier to hand-code, debug and maintain after the initial learning curve is overcome. Admittedly, I am not an expert in this area and any comments will be helpful.

Comment: @asinix Threads are hard, because concurrency is hard. If you just want to respond to events (like user input, network action, *timers*, ie. mostly just waiting), you should have a single threaded event loop. You can write it yourself, if re-inventing the wheel is your thing, but using a tested library/framework is usually wiser. Adding threads is trouble, so before you do that, better be sure you get enough benefits. Using threads to run timers isn't.

Comment: @hyde Even if a single threaded event loop is used, there will be need for some form of support from the OS to set a timer and then fire an event when the timer expires.  No matter which library is used, on Linux, timers can either generate a signal or execute a function in a separate thread created by the OS. There are limitations on the number of such signals which can be queued per process (see timer_create(2)) so you cannot avoid the creation of  threads (albeit by the OS) for processing timers on Linux.  In any event, your suggestions provide useful info for me.

Comment: @asinix normally in Linux, event loop is programmed around `select` (or equivalent) system call, with timeout set to next timer event. No interrupting timer mechanism or signals needed. There can be an arbitrary number of timers.

Comment: @hyde I am using epoll  (select is archaic). Epolls (select) monitor fds. There is no file description associated with timers.  May be I am missing something. Can you identify which system call you are referring to, to set timers to be used with select or epoll?

Comment: @asinix with `epoll`, I think you'll need to use the `timerfd_xxxxx` functions for timeouts? I've always needed to write POSIX code and used just `poll`, which takes timeout parameters (presumably implemented in Linux  using timerfd stuff?).

Comment: @hyde  Thats it!!  Thanks a lot. Now I understand why you were talking about event loop regarding timers! Certainly an elegant solution.

Comment: @hyde Can you take a look at this  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458389/timer-using-timerfd-create-and-timerfd-settime-continually-expires-even-thou]? Its a question related to timerfd. There are no related tags and I do not have enough votes to add one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you need more than one timer in your process, so you might want the POSIX `timer_*` family of functions (`timer_create`, `timer_settime`, etc).  They have nanosecond granularity.  You can specify a few different actions for when the timer expires: raise a signal, or call a function from a separate thread.  You have to link with `-lrt` to use these functions.

There is also `timerfd_create`, which let you detect timer expiration by a file becoming readable, using `poll` or `select` or their relatives.

Comment: I am going through it and it appears to be exactly what I am looking for (and a lot more!).

Comment: From the man page for sigevent: "..SIGEV_THREAD ...Among the implementation possibilities here are that each timer notification could result in the creation of a new thread, or that a single thread is created to receive all notifications.."  Creating a thread for each notification would be an overkill to say the least. Is there a way to have "a single thread created to receive all notifications" ?

Comment: @asinix: From a look at the glibc source, the latter is what it actually does.  It creates one helper thread which does nothing except sit and wait for signals.  Then it uses `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` to ensure that the timer signal goes to the helper thread, which is told to call your function when your timer goes off.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that glibc does what I suggested in my question -:) Of course, glibc does a lot more than I thought...

Comment: @asinix: Maybe the key difference is that this approach doesn't have to spin while waiting for a timer to expire; since expiration raises a signal, the helper thread can `sigwaitinfo()` and use no CPU while waiting.  So it needn't be "ridiculously inefficient".

Comment: I feel very comfortable with the code I have written based upon your suggestions... I get segmentation fault. gdb says: "at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_create.c:131
131 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_create.c: No such file or directory."  Indeed there is no file timer_create.c.  I am compiling with -lrt. Do I need to install some package to get the missing files?

Comment: This message just means that gdb is trying to show you the source line where the crash occurs, but it was inside glibc code and it doesn't know where to find the glibc source code.  You could install the source somewhere and use the `dir` command in gdb to tell it where they are, which might help in debugging, but their absence isn't the cause of your crash.  You should probably ask a separate question about that, with a complete test case.

Comment: But it either means you are calling `timer_create` incorrectly (read its man page carefully) or else that there is a bug in glibc.  By [Jeff Atwood's First Rule](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) you should assume the first case until you can prove otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GLib and its timeout sources ([`g_timeout_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add), [`g_timeout_add_seconds()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds), etc.), then you will need to run a [GLib main loop](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en) ([`GMainLoop`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html)) and run the rest of your application in a main loop callback too. This will be quite a large change if your application isn’t already written in an event-driven style, but would be necessary for polling sockets or running a UI anyway.

There’s an example of how to use a timeout source in an application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54625492/2931197).

Note that GLib’s timer API (`g_timer_*()`) is not for running callbacks after a certain timeout, it’s for timing how long something takes (like a stopwatch). It’s not relevant here.

Comment: I generally prefer to use basic Linux system calls and avoid using other libraries unless absolutely required because I am not planning to port my code to any other platform.  I already have my own event loop per thread and introducing GLib main loop will be an over-kill just for this requirement. The solution suggested by Nate works just fine. I will, however, look into the Glib functions you suggested.

Comment: Sure, GLib is only one solution — I thought it merited explanation in an answer, though, since the question is tagged as `glib` and you mentioned its timer functions explicitly in the question. :)

Comment: For me, every explanation is educational as I am not an expert in this area. I find a lot of solutions hidden somewhere in GLib so I did tag it just in case there was no other easy solution.