# timer using timerfd_create() and timerfd_settime() continually expires even though interval is set to zero

Tags: linux, timer, epoll

Here is the stripped-down code. The timer expires(reported by epoll_wait) in time but even though interval is set to zero, epoll_wait continually triggers a ready-to-read event (EPOLLIN) for the timer fd. Should it not be triggered just once as interval is set to 0?

```
timerFd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_NONBLOCK | TFD_CLOEXEC);
struct itimerspec *my_itimerspec_new, *my_itimerspec_old;
my_itimerspec_new = malloc(sizeof(struct itimerspec));
my_itimerspec_old = malloc(sizeof(struct itimerspec));

bzero(my_itimerspec_new, sizeof(struct itimerspec));
bzero(my_itimerspec_old, sizeof(struct itimerspec));


my_itimerspec_new->it_value.tv_sec  = 60;
my_itimerspec_new->it_value.tv_nsec = 0; 
my_itimerspec_new->it_interval.tv_sec  = 0; 
my_itimerspec_new->it_interval.tv_nsec = 0; 

my_itimerspec_old->it_value.tv_sec  = 0; 
my_itimerspec_old->it_value.tv_nsec = 0; 
my_itimerspec_old->it_interval.tv_sec  = 0; 
my_itimerspec_old->it_interval.tv_nsec = 0; 

timerfd_settime(timerFd, 0, my_itimerspec_new, my_itimerspec_old);
```

Comment: Do you ever read the timer? Needs a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you use `malloc`? As far as I can see, there's no need. Anyway, looking at *this* partial code, timer should indeed expire just once. So you should write a [mcve].

Comment: @hyde  I have simplified the code from the bigger application. No need for malloc here.  I found the problem... I was not reading the timer as Shawn pointed out. I thought with EPOLLET it was not needed. Of course, in the production code I would have to read and check what triggered the Epoll_wait loop. When EPOLLET and EPOLLONESHOT are used, should the rearming be done after reading until EAGAIN is returned, before reading or it does not matter?  May be this should be a fresh question.

Comment: @Shawn Your question is spot on! Problem fixed. Related question: When EPOLLET and EPOLLONESHOT are used, should the rearming be done after reading until EAGAIN is returned, before reading or it does not matter?

Comment: @Shawn If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Probably after reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`epoll`, `poll()`, `select()`, etc. will tell you if the timer descriptor is readable without blocking. It becomes readable when the timer expires and remains so until you `read()` a 64 bit unsigned integer from it that contains the count of times the timer expired since the last read. If you don't do that, it continues to poll as readable (modulo however ET and ONESHOT options affect the behavior if you're using those)